how to remove header from className in Flutter webview 4.x.x
i want to remove header with class name "logo me-ld-4" in flutter webview but i am unable to do it, i tried running runJavaScript method but it doesn't work
document.getElementsByClassName('logo me-lg-4')[0].style.display='none';

this js code works on browser for removing header.
WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(url));

return Scaffold(
      body: WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
    );

help is appreciated.
